# How to migrate from xcart to Magento?

Tags: magento-1, migration

I want to migrate from xcart to Magento. What steps should I follow and what can be the challenges which I can face?

If some one has done this please suggest some ideas which can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy, automated way to migrate from x-cart to Magento so the main challenges you will face are having to export all your products and customers manually from x-cart and import these into Magento either using Magento's built in Import tools or [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) which is my preferred option.

With this in mind I would suggest the best way forward is to get the new Magento store set up on a temporary / new URL with some example products e.g. manually create a few new versions of existing x-cart products which will help identify all the new Magento Attributes you need and get you used to simple, grouped, configurable products. Once you are happy with the way the new Magento store looks and functions start work on the export form x-cart into Magento.

Comment: Do we have configurable and bundle products in Xacrt?

Comment: No you don't as such as X-Cart has a different set up / naming conventions but I would suggest you read up about the Magento product types via the wiki http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype and create test products using each to see which meet your existing X-Cart set up the closest.

The migration will take a lot of work but will be worth it in the end as X-Cart is not a great e-commerce system IMHO!